# Prompt command syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax, command

Im currently reading eloquent JavaScript and this was an example for using the prompt command:

var theNumber = **Number**(prompt("Pick a number", " "));

Why does the bolded need to be there? Is that the way of letting the computer know what kind of entry was entered? If it was a set of words would it be String(prompt("Pick a number", " "));

Comment: Welcome to [the documentation on Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

Answer (score 1):

If you just used:

`var theNumber = prompt("Pick a number");`

The variable `theNumber` would be set to a string. For example if the user entered 5, then `theNumber` would equal `"5"`. `Number()` is a function in javascript that will convert a string to a number, meaning if you use:

`var theNumber = Number(prompt("Pick a number"));`

Then `theNumber` would equal `5` or whatever the user entered.

If you wanted to convert a number back into a string, you would use:

`var stringOfTheNumber = theNumber.ToString();`

Comment: Also worth mentioning that `Number()` is considered harmful. `Number("0x100")` returns `256`. Instead use `Number.parseInt(..., 10)` where in that case you'll get `0`.

Comment: Also it is important to use try, catch statements in the event that the user doesn't enter a number.